# Date coming out in a strange format

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, .net-3.5

I have the following code which works:

```
<%@ WebService Language="C#" Class="Absences" %>

using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Script;
using System.Web.Script.Services;
using System.Web.Services;

public class Absence
{
    public string name;
    public DateTime from;
    public DateTime to;

    public Absence(string m_name, DateTime m_from, DateTime m_to)
    {
        name = m_name;
        from = m_from;
        to = m_to;
    }

    public Absence() { }
}

[ScriptService]
public class Absences : WebService {
    List<Absence> Absence = new List<Absence>();

    SqlConnection connection;
    SqlCommand command;
    SqlDataReader reader;

    [WebMethod()]
    public List<Absence> GetAbsences(string strDateYear, string strDateMonth, string strDateDay)
    {
        var absences = new List<Absence>();

        using (connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["connString"]))
        {

            using (command = new SqlCommand(@"select full_name, from_date, to_date from table1", connection))
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    using (reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        int NameIndex = reader.GetOrdinal("full_name");
                        int FromIndex = reader.GetOrdinal("from_date");
                        int ToIndex = reader.GetOrdinal("to_date");

                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            absences.Add(new Absence(reader.GetString(NameIndex), reader.GetDateTime(FromIndex), reader.GetDateTime(ToIndex)));
                        }
                    }
                }

        }

        return absences;
    }
}
```

the only problem are the dates, they are coming out in a strange format in the JSON data such as:

`"from":"\/Date(1353456000000)\/"`

How can I get the date to the following format `dd/mm/yy`?

Comment: how is this related to jQuery?

Comment: This will help you.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10143678/parsing-a-date-returned-as-json-in-net

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4622172/how-to-pass-a-datetime-value-to-a-webmethod-asmx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution

```
var jsondateString = "\/Date(1353456000000)\/".substr(6);
var current = new Date(parseInt(jsondateString ));
var month = current.getMonth() + 1;
var day = current.getDate();
var year = current.getFullYear();
var date = day + "/" + month + "/" + year;
alert(date);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
var data = {"from":"\/Date(1353456000000)\/"};
var parsedDate = new Date(parseInt(data.from.substr(6)));
var curr_date = parsedDate.getDate();
var curr_month = parsedDate.getMonth() + 1;
var curr_year = parsedDate.getFullYear();
alert(curr_date + "/" + curr_month + "/" + curr_year);
```

Working fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/tariqulazam/a2xZM/

Comment: (data.from.substr(6))); wont work as Date(1353456000000) has ) at end not to mention whether the \/ will also be seen

Comment: @PaulSullivan - See the fiddle. And when you do the parseInt, all the non numeric things at the end is stripped off.

Comment: well blow me over... that is some magic! (and some seriously over zealous coding in parseInt...

Answer (score 0):

You can use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) for it. Its a very flexible open source library.

> A 5kb javascript date library for parsing, validating, manipulating, and formatting dates.

```
moment("/Date(1198908717056-0700)/").valueOf(); // 1198908717056
```